# Typo3 content importer

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack, typo3

I need to build an importer tool which shall read a xhtml/xml file with predefined structure and import the content to the typo3 backend system in page structure so that they can later be edited using standard UI based editing features in typo3. I am thinking about using a .NET webform and HtmlAgilityPack library based solution with C# for the importer tool. My theory is to traverse the input file, find predefined tags and determine page title, content and insert those data directly into the typo3 database in correct format. But ofcourse, for that to work I'll have to create a typo3 template first. Is this the right way of doing this? How shall I go about with the development? Is there a better alternative to HtmlAgilityPack library for my need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well depends on your skills.

TYPO3 uses a custom XML format for the import/export tool. So if you are fluent in XSLT, you might just convert the XML file.

If you are more of a C# guy, than you may just add the content to the DB directly. Just make sure that there is no concurrent edit while doing this. And fill the other fields too, mainly the timestamp fields - just have a look what is filled if you create some sample pages and content.

After import, you should run the reference index updater (DB Check, EXT:lowlevel must be installed).

You do not need a template for inserting the data. Actually TYPO3 works fine without a template. You just need a template to generate the frontend output ;) - which is usually needed for a website.

Comment: the t3d file it uses for import export is relatively complex than direct database insert. Can you please clarify on the "Index Updater"... is it a typo3 extension or some external tool?

Comment: It is part of the TYPO3 (sysext lowlevel) and shows up under Admin Tools --> DB Check --> Check and update global reference index (dropdown).
The reference index is used to show the relations in the info popup so editors can see how an element is used.

Comment: Anyway, my suggestion is to use direct db inserts. This leaves you all the freedom you need. Just run the update reference index afterwards. You can do so also via the typo3/cli_dispatch.php (see instructions in the module I showed you above).